# PowerBI Measure - Previous Quarter With Filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure to calculate the sum of sales for the previous quarter with a filter.

This is what I tried:

```
PQ Retail Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(MASTER_SALES_REPORTING_COMPETITION[Retail Sales $]), 
                  FILTER(MASTER_SALES_REPORTING_COMPETITION, 
                         MASTER_SALES_REPORTING_COMPETITION[Vendor Grouped] = "Company A"), 
                  PREVIOUSQUARTER(DateDim[Date]))
```

Is there a logical error with the dax? PowerBI doesn't pick up any errors however I get a blank result.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your DateDim table marked as a Date table?

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues with your DAX (except unecessary use of FILTER function). There must be some problem in your data model, or in your filter context, but without additional information it's impossible to tell. It'd be helpfull if you provide data model snapshot with all relevant tables and relations, and report snapshot where you are trying to use the formula, with all relevant filters and slicers. A specific  example with data and expected result would be helpfull too.

Comment: One thing you can do: break your formula in 2 measures: first, just previous quarter sales (without filter), and second, reuse the fist measure with the filter. You can then test these measures separately and see where the problem is.

Comment: @mxix yes it is marked at a date table.